# I cannot find this syntax error

Tags: javascript, push-notification, phonegap-build

I'm going to feel like a complete idiot once this is pointed out to me, but I've got a syntax error I cannot figure out where the issue is coming from. Here is my code (error appears on last line but I doubt its that line that caused that):

```
// handle GCM notifications for Android
 function onNotificationGCM(e) {
 switch( e.event )
 {
     case 'registered':
     if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
     {
         // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
         // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
         PushWoosh.appCode = "33F93-5013B";
         PushWoosh.register(e.regid, function(data) {
                     alert("PushWoosh register success: " + JSON.stringify(data));
                 }, function(errorregistration) {
                     alert("Couldn't register with PushWoosh" +  errorregistration);
                 });

     }
 break;
```

Thanks guys, I'm feeling like an idiot here and had a frustrating day.

Comment: Hint: http://jslint.com or http://jshint.com

Comment: Can you give the actual error?

Comment: According to javascriptlint.com it is "SytaxError: syntax error". Though I found out if I remove a particular part of my code the error goes away. Let me edit it and show what I think the trouble code is. Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `onNotificationGCM()` function is not closed, and neither is the switch block contained within it.  The JavaScript parser is expecting to see two additional close braces (`}`) but the input file terminates before they are seen.

My guess is that you need to add these two braces after your `break;` statement, prior to the assignment of `PushNotification.prototype.register`.

Comment: Bah I would upvote you but I don't have the rep. I'll mark it though. In an edit I'll put the code that fixed it. Thanks guys you are all awesome!